# delaydexpansion and endlocal conflict, any solution?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, delayedvariableexpansion

I find it an embarrassment when I want to use `endlocal` inside an `if`/`for` statement.

Please check this delayexpe.bat :

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set dvar=oldata

if "1" == "1" (
    REM Deliberately need a delayed-expansion context
    set dvar=newdata
    echo [1]=%dvar%
    echo [2]=!dvar!

    REM I want to set outvar for my calling environment, so I need endlocal.
    endlocal & ( set "outvar=!dvar!" )
    
    REM Normally, here will be an `exit /b 0`.
)

echo [3]outvar=%outvar%

exit /b 0
```

The output is:

```
[1]=oldata
[2]=newdata
[3]outvar=!dvar!
```

[image]

It means that delayed-expansion syntax `!dvar!` does not take effect on the same statement as `endlocal`, BUT, I need that `endlocal` because I now want to change my parent environment.

Moving `endlocal` outside the whole `if` block so to use `endlocal & ( set "outvar=%some_temp_var%" )` may be a solution, but complicates the code flow.

I just can't figure out the reason why CMD refuse to expand `!dvar!` along side with `endlocal`. Can anyone clarify this?

Comment: `For /f delims^= %%v IN ("!dvAR!") Do Endlocal & Set "returnvar=%%v"`

Comment: the reason is that once the endlocal command has been parsed, if the calling environment does not have delayed expansion enabled, `!` is no longer considered a command token marking the beginning / end of a variable.

Comment: @T3RR0R Thank you, your `For /f delims^=` trick do the right job for me. You can write it as answer.

Comment: It would be even easier to change the __IF__ condition to `if not "1" == "1" goto Label` and do not use a command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)` at all which avoids also the need to use delayed expansion.